# Import Excel file in angular2

Tags: angular, wijmo

How to import excel file in angular2? I trying to use wijmo FlexGridXlsxConverter load method but I am getting an error:
Property 'xlsx' does not exist on type 'typeof grid'.

Comment: have you worked on ng2-file-upload package to import the file?

Comment: No I trying to use wijmo. I am referring this http://wijmo.com/blog/flexgrid-client-side-importingexporting/. Is there any other way?

Comment: http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular2/ExcelImportExport/ExcelImportExport/FlexGridImportExport.htm

Also, download the Wijmo library, and look in the Samples/TS/Angular2/ for ExcelImportExport - it's a complete demo project with full source code you can pick apart and adapt.